# Avoiding Locator Bloat

Tags: mvvm-light

Just starting a new project with MVVM light after a few years hiatus. I am wiring up my first VM using the ViewModelLocator and I see that for each new view model we need to create a new property. I am just wondering how to avoid this as the app may end up having quite a few view models (50+). I have gotten it to work using a value converter but then I loose intellisence in the XAML editor.

Any examples from those who may have a solution to this is appreciated.

Note - here is a solution using a value converter, so I can then just pass the parameter into some IoC and get the VM, but then I loose intellisense (WelcomeTitle gets the squiggle).

```
<Window x:Class="My.MainWindow" 
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, 
Converter={StaticResource Locator}, ConverterParameter='foo'}">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock FontSize="36"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Foreground="Purple"
               Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Update:
Here is another approach, better than using a converter, but still suffers from WelcomeTitle squiggle because the XAML editor does not know the type. I wonder if this effects "blendability"? (I do not have blend handy.)

http://maartendewilde.blogspot.com/2011/01/auto-viewmodel-binding-with-ninject.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the intellisense, you can try yet more boilerplate on the resources?

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to contain things
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">UserID</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TK">UserName</typeparam>
public class MyDictionary<T,TK> : Dictionary<T,TK>
```

or what about using a shared resource dictionary to make intellisense happy?

Dependency injection is a good way to reduce redundant locator code. It involves a generic way of registering service or model providers. [From the MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx)

If you have to create a new property for each view model, it may indicate a weakness in your actual model. When working with VMs I usually find that they are reductive, in that the model contains all pertinent data, and view models get constructed as a subset of properties important to that view.

It is not uncommon for a large project to have 50+ view models.

Comment: My impression from researching MVVM Light was that each ViewModel needs a backing property in the ViewModelLocator. From what I remember, each View generally has it's own ViewModel. So if there are 50+ View Models (as we have established a being perfectly normal) then how do I avoid a large ViewModelLocator class with 50+ properties?

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate the help. In the article you linked he still has to create a new property for each view model. Perhaps I am being pedantic about the whole issue.

Comment: I wonder if dynamic types or a dictionary on type could solve it?

Comment: Yep, see my update, it's actually a pretty good solution. It's basically doing just that but inside the IoC container. Only problem is the XAML editor does not know the type and it shows a warning. This might be a resharper only warning, I am not sure. I can see the form rendered in the WYSIWYG editor.